# Open source video player that supports DXVA on XP?

Tags: windows, video

Is there a open source video player that can use DXVA on XP 32bit? Video card is GT440. Currently using PotPlayer which uses DXVA successfully but is closed source.

Comment: Why do you need it to be open source?

Comment: Maybe they *want* it to be open-source?

Comment: Well, that's not a *real* reason is it? If you need something open source, there's got to be some reason for that – maybe "supporting open source community" or trying to modify the source code. Whatever it is, it'd just help to know *why* in order to make it easier to address a specific problem, and thus provide better answers. Not to mention possible [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) — or do you disagree with that? @gra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MPC-HC](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/) supports DXVA but only for [for some video cards](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/DXVASupport.html).